# Lumen does not receive any file from Form Data that was sent

Tags: php, laravel, multipartform-data, lumen

I checked in chrome the Headers send for Form Data which looks something like this:

[image: Chrome Headers Form Data]

Now to be that looks like there is an image file named "files" in my POST request.

Now in my Controller in Lumen I do the following debug to try get the file:

```
return response([$request->hasFile('files'), $request->file('files'), $request->get('files')]);
```

However what I get is this in the response:

> [true,{},null]

This is the request I make in my react app:

```
const formData  = new FormData();
formData.append("files", this.state.productData[key][0]);

        fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/products/submit`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        })
```

Does anyone know whats wrong with what I am doing to get the image?

Comment: Are you sure you're using POST and not PUT/PATCH?

Comment: @HafezDivandari I have added my JS code to the post above. It is definitely a POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$request->file()` method returns an instance of the `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` class and appears as a `{}` on your response but you're file is uploaded an is valid when `$request->hasFile()` is `true` so you can retrieve its properties like this:

```php
if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
    $files = $request->file('files');

    return response()->json([
        'path' => $files->path(),
        'name' => $files->getClientOriginalName(),
        'size' => $files->getSize()
    ]);
}
```

Or if you want to get response as a file:

```php
if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
    return response()->file(
        $request->file('files')->path()
    );
}
```

See Laravel docs for [retrieving and storing uploaded files](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#files).

Note: I recommend to use a name other than `files` because `$request->files` is an instance of the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag` class and causes a conflict when you want to use `$request->files` as a shorthand of `$request->file('files')`.